# Spring Boot fails to parse JSON sent from Angular

Tags: json, angular, spring-boot

I am getting this **error** when I call the Angular function:

```
    2019-08-07 11:13:37.444  WARN 16320 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.ecommerce.app.securedapp.model.viewModels.CartOwnerUsernameModel` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.ecommerce.app.securedapp.model.viewModels.CartOwnerUsernameModel` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]]
```

The **Angular** function:

```
    getCartProducts() {
    let username = sessionStorage.getItem(AUTHENTICATED_USER)
    return this.http.post<any>(`${API_URL}/order/details/cart`, {username})
    }
```

Now in intelliJ project I have: 
**CartOwnerUsernameModel** class:

```
    public class CartOwnerUsernameModel {

    private String username;

    public CartOwnerUsernameModel(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
//getters, setters and toString
```

The method in controller class is :

```
@PostMapping(
            value = "/cart",
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<List<CartModelView>> getCartItems(@RequestBody CartOwnerUsernameModel cartOwnerUsernameModel) {
        System.out.println(cartOwnerUsernameModel);
        return orderDetailsService.retrieveCartItems(cartOwnerUsernameModel);
    }
```

**Note** that it is not even printing the cartOwnerUsernameModel instance in console. 
When I look at the request in chrome browser I see the following:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/order/details/cart
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

And the request payload is :

```
{"username":"dan"}
```

Please let me know what you think is the problem or if the information here is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the jackson library, the default constructor of the class is required.

```java
public class CartOwnerUsernameModel {

    private String username;

    public CartOwnerUsernameModel() {
    }

    public CartOwnerUsernameModel(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

//Need same resolve for kotlin, Please!

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. So I assume in the "back" the JSON parser first creates an empty instance and thats why it needs the default constructor ?

Comment: In my memory, I create an object using reflection, which calls the default constructor.